# Include partial with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to include a menu in my page with this code:

```
<%- include ../common/menu %>
```

Here is the file directory: /views/common/menu.ejs

Here is my menu.ejs:

```
<div class="button" id="menu-btn">
    <a class="btn-open" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul class="wrap-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Welcome Page</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="/main">Main Page</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/vungtau">Vũng Tàu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/suoimo">Đồng Nai - Suối Mơ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/dalat">Đà Lạt</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/video">Video</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I got a 500 Internal Server Error but I did not know why? I'm following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

I did many search on google but it s no help.

Comment: You should accept solution for this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<%- include('../common/menu.ejs') %>
```

[docs http://ejs.co/#docs](http://ejs.co/#docs)

Comment: If your getting a 500 error, that means your server is not responding due to an unspecified error, [500 error](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error). 1. try restarting server, 2. check your file structure, maybe  your path has a mistake, 3. Includes are relative to the template with the include call. (This requires the 'filename' option.) For example if you have "./views/users.ejs" and "./views/user/show.ejs" you would use <%- include('user/show'); %>.

You'll want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

If I use this folder structure:

```
../views/partials/header.ejs
../views/partials/footer.ejs
../views/users.ejs
```

then in users.ejs:

```
<%- include('./partials/header.ejs') %>
<body>
...
</body>
<%- include("./partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this new syntax

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>
<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```